# image with id in its name? image-name-93943.jpg

Tags: seo

I have a website that I have some news there and photos.

So, for example:

> Barack Obama out in NY.

for this I have some pictures:

```
mywebsite.com/barack-obama-out-in-NY-157475445.jpg
mywebsite.com/barack-obama-out-in-NY-257475445.jpg
mywebsite.com/barack-obama-out-in-NY-357475445.jpg
```

image title and after it the image number (1, 2, 3) with post_id (57475445).

Is it ok for SEO or the id in the image name could be a bad practise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing is important to search engines about an image tag is its title and alternative text attributes. Also notice that defining width and height attributes in an image tag can surely help the search engine crawler to fetch the context so much better.
Hope this was helpfull for you. Regards.